# Best practices of naming the keys for Symfony translation component

Tags: symfony, translation

My YML translation files are becoming bigger and bigger, is there any hints or best practices to name the keys in a very straightfoward and easy-to-grasp way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the best practices book SensioLabs deliver few weeks ago here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

There's a part about best practice for translations.

Hope it'll helps !

Answer (score 0):

from Sylius (ProductBundle/.../messages.en.yml):

```
sylius:
  form:
    product:
        name: Name
        description: Description
        attributes: Attributes
        ...
    product_variant:
        available_on: Available on
    product_prototype:
        name: Name
        attributes: Attributes
        options: Options
```